# PHP preg_replace not replacing input code with html code

Tags: php, preg-replace

I am trying to make code that will take input of a string, search teh string for certain characters and replace them with the html code.

This is what i have done so far

```
function htmlsymbolsconvertor($tmp1)
    {

        $symbols = array ('£', '-');
        $htmlcode = array ('&#163;', '&#45;');

        return preg_replace($symbols, $htmlcode, $tmp1);
    }
```

however it does not change the input character to the html code.

i have probably not understood php.net page on using preg_replace, and i have not found anything out there that already has something similar to what i am trying to do or i could modify.

although i am not sure if preg_replace is the right php code i need to use either. eventually once i get the code working symbols and htmlcode will be put into a database but i can do that easily i just need to get the basic code working.

if there is another topic on stackoverflow that covers what i am asking please point me to it i apologise for duplication.

Comment: `preg_replace` expects a valid regex pattern. Use `str_replace()` instead.

Comment: use [`htmlentities`](http://us.php.net/htmlentities), it does exactly that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't create things that have been already written.

> [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) — Convert special characters to HTML entities
>
> [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) - Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities

This function changes special characters for html entites.

The translations performed are:

- '&' (ampersand) becomes '&'
- '"' (double quote) becomes '"' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
- "'" (single quote) becomes ''' (or ') only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
- '<' (less than) becomes '<'
- '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt

Comment: Thank you for the responses, htmlentties seems to do the job, apart from not converting letters and numbers and sapce to html code but i can live with that. str_replace will defintely be useful for a future code i will be doing thank you all for yoru help, i am not sure how i can mark you for the help if you advise i will mark you for good help :)

Comment: @AndrewCrawford - you just need to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: mmmm not sure why, but when i am trying to covert £ to html code it works if it is itself, but when it is with any other character it just display a empty field. i am using htmlentities. if code is required i will post after this, but i am using the html entities basically the way the example on php.net shows with the exception i am using html5